# Dimension of unary log factor

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

[image]

This is from Hugo Larochelles NN course . 
What is the Dimension of the unary log factors ?

I think as Weights are input_size*n_classes and X is seq_len*input_size, When we multiply, we get seq_len * n_classes. Then we need for x_k , so it is 1*n_classes .

Is this the dimension ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the dimension of the unary log factors should be 1 x N_states. It is usually obtained from the last fully connected layer of the NN, after applying the softmax function.